# How can i call a saga for an api call while it is running the previous call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

So the second action is being called while 1st action is running in saga.
I do get the response of the 1st action but not that of the second one.

```
this.props.actions.FetchRequest(payload1)
this.props.actions.FetchRequest(payload2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two saga helpers **takeevery** and **takelatest**

`takeevery` is use to perform on every dispatched actions and

`takeLatest` is use to perform task only latest dispatched action and cancels any pending task started previously.

Docs: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/